# std::terminate handler is not called

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I was trying sample program to understand how std::terminate feature works - but on VC++ 2019 I always get an un-handled exception error:

```
// set_terminate example

#include <iostream>       // std::cerr
#include <exception>      // std::set_terminate
#include <cstdlib>        // std::abort

    void myterminate () {
      std::cerr << "terminate handler called\n";
      abort();  // forces abnormal termination
    }
    
    int main (void) {
      std::set_terminate (myterminate);
      throw 0;  // unhandled exception: calls terminate handler
      return 0;
    }
```

I always get the below error in VC++ -

```
Unhandled exception at 0x761340B2 in Abandon.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0097FAE8
```

Whereas the expected output is -

```
terminate handler called
Aborted
```

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: does this code compiles? coz abort() belongs to std::

Comment: It compiles fine in VC++ 2019

Comment: Run it outside the debugger. ctrl-F5

Comment: Running outside debugger mode does produces the expected result I see the handler getting called followed by abort message window - can you please let me know what is ctrl + F5 (running outside debugger mode) does?

Comment: It runs the program without the debugger attached. Same thing if you double click it in explorer.

Comment: @Programmer -- concerning `abort()` versus `std::abort()`, when a source file uses `#include <cstdlib>`, all of the names in that header are defined inside `std`; they also **might** be defined in the global namespace. And conversely, when a source file uses `#include <stdlib.h>`, all of the names in that header are defined in the global namespace, and they also **might** be defined inside `std`. Portable code uses either `#include <cstdlib>` and `std::abort()` or `#include <stdlib.h>` and `abort()`.